# Cannot generate a model in cmd line Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I just started learning ruby on rails today. I am following the book Rails For PHP Developers. Anyhow, when I type rails g model Subscribers the next line says "invoke active record". I had no trouble creating a controller from the cmd line, so how come my model is not generating. Which means the model file is not being created in models directory.

Comment: I think it's best practice to use singular model names: `rails generate model Subscriber`. Anyhow, your model should be created. `Invoke ActiveRecord` is an expected line in the output, as the Rails generator passes your command to ActivRecord, Rails' standard ORM.

Comment: Actually you should see something like this: `      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20121225215234_create_subscribers.rb
      create    app/models/subscriber.rb`

Comment: I typed rails generate model Subscriber and the model is still not creating. It showed 'invoke active_record. It goes on to say "Please install the mysql adapter: gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter.

Comment: This suggests another problem. Have you setup your database correctly? What OS are you running, what DB do you want to use?

Comment: try `rails g model subscriber` and make sure your gem file and etc is up to date by running `bundle update`.

Comment: I did the bundle update and same result. Here is my database

Comment: development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: newsletter_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

Comment: Thanks for the response. I still cannot figure this simple issue out.

Comment: Update your post with contents of gemfile and database.yml, also include your OS

Comment: source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

Comment: gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

Comment: # SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: newsletter_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the mysql2 gem to your gemfile. Then run bundle install and try it again.

When learning rails and on your local machine it's best to stay with the defaul SQLite database.  You must have changed the config/database.yml to use MySQL for your development environment and that requires you to have the MySQL adapter installed.

Note: Use the mysql2 gem, not the mysql gem.  It'll save you a lot of grief.

Comment: I will add and see. Thank you. One more question. I am coming from a LAMP environment using php. On my localhost server, I would just go to localhost://phpmyadmin to access my database. How do I actually access the database with ruby on rails?

Comment: if it was a mysql db you could still use phpmyadmin? if it was sql lite or postgres use command line, or use pgAdmin GUI app - note in rails you can use `rails console` which is very powerful, you can inspect your data live using the activerecord objects - I recommend checking out railsguides - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html